# No change in Texture Paint Brush Sensitivity on changing Pressure Curves

Tags: texture-painting

In Blender2.79b/Windows10-64bit,**stroke's painted with mouse**,using the texDraw brush(Strength = 1,Blend = Mix ) on the default DiffuseColor layer(No Alpha) ***work fine*** .

However on switching to a **pressure sensitive tablet**(on latest drivers),the stroke is suddenly next to **invisible**.On changing the ***Pressure Curve***  for the brush from the  Original [origin (0,0,)end(1,1)] to a New[origin (0,1),end(1,1)],the tablet stroke still remains next to invisible.

Normally, if **the software recognises the MouseStroke** it means the **machine's hardware is able to compute the stroke realtime** but when it does not detect the pressure sensitivity of the tablet ,it does mean that **the machine is not able to compute and render the Pressure sensitive stroke realtime**.

On **disabling pressure sensitivity by changing the PressureCurve** to a Flat (0,1)(1,1) this issue is normally solved.
However in this case ,the solution is not working. 
Is there any other way to completely turnoff pressure sensitivity ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blender2.79 ,Texture Paint has an ***"Accumulate"*** Option[Texture Paint Mode->Tools->texDraw brush-->Accumulate] which allows the TexDraw brush to daub strokes on top of the previous daub.This makes the brush daub thicker and hence visible.

However,this option is **"OFF" by default**. By **toggling it "ON"** the *Accumulate* featured is turned "On" and a visible brush stroke is rendered (also pressure sensitivity is supported) .

[image]

Comment: Priceless. I have never seen this before. Thanks.

Comment: Wasted an entire hour trying to figure out these options.It's great ,that  it worked.